# How to delete Resque ActiveJob Queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activejob

I am using Resque with Redis as the queuing backend via ActiveJob. How do I clear all queues to prevent jobs from running again.

From the docs, I see that I can do

```
Resque::Job.destroy(queue_name, "Job_CLass_Name")
```

So in my case, I'm using a default queue and my Job class name is `NotificationJob`, this is what I'm doing from the console on Heroku:

```
Resque::Job.destroy("default", "NotificationJob")
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveJob uses a wrapper class around your job class. So for Resque, the wrapper class name is `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper`.

For the queue name, I'll advise you check the available queues you have via `Resque.queues`. Sometimes, the environment name will be appended to the default queue name. So in your case, you can try:

```
Resque.destroy("#{environment_name}_default", "ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper")
```

Hopefully, this helps